# Modify data member of base class from constructor of derived class in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

I can't understand the output of this code. I expect `10` to be printed, but the output is `85`. Can someone explain what's happening?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{  
    public:   
        int x=3;
        A(int a) : x(a) {}
};

class B: public A
{   
    public:  
        int y = 10;
        B() : A(y) {}
};

int main()
{
    B b;    
    cout << b.x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But, changing it to:

```
class B: public A
{   
    public:  
        int y = 10;
        B(int s) : A(s) {}
};

int main()
{
    B b(4); 
    cout << b.x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It works as expected (prints 4).

Comment: The [initialization order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Initialization_order) is not what you expect.

Comment: warnings are your friend: [warning: '*<unknown>.B::y' is used uninitialized in this function -Wuninitialized](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5691a969e6a497a)

Comment: @user1810087 i didn't get any warning when I ran the code on terminal

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the link! It explained neatly.

Comment: @spab note the flags ` -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. I think most developers would agree to enable warnings as extreme as possible and only disable if unavoidable. For VS it would be /W4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by the link in @Someprogrammerdude's comment:

The order of member initializers in the list is irrelevant: the actual order of initialization is as follows:

1. If the constructor is for the most-derived class, virtual bases are initialized in the order in which they appear in depth-first left-to-right traversal of the base class declarations (left-to-right refers to the appearance in base-specifier lists)
2. Then, direct bases are initialized in left-to-right order as they appear in this class's base-specifier list
3. Then, non-static data member are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition.
4. Finally, the body of the constructor is executed

Answer (score 6):

This is called "undefined behavior".

Base classes are ***constructed first***, before the class members are constructed.

In this case, you're passing the contents of an uninitialized class member to the base class's constructor.

Just because you have an initialization statement for the class member that appears on a previous line, in the `.cpp` file, doesn't mean that this is the initialization order. C++ does not always work this way. You're passing an uninitialized `y` to the base class's constructor, and then when the base class returns the subclass gets constructed, setting `y` to what it's initialized to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But im not sure how this is undefined behavior. @Someprogrammerdude's answer cleared it to me. I'm accepting that answer.

Comment: @spab I'm not sure what you mean - none of the people who posted answers are named Someprogrammerdude.

Comment: You observed undefined behavior yourself: a nonsensical result.

Comment: @DavidZ The 1st comment to the question is by Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sure. But the documentation directed by Someprogrammerdude gave an understanding on a bigger level. Some parts of your answer seemed vague/misleading to me:
1) "Base classes are constructed first, before the class members are constructed" - maybe you meant 'class members are initialized'
2) "When the base class returns the subclass gets constructed" - this doesn't explicitly state when the class members are initialized.

Someprogrammerdude's answer clarified my question completely.

Thanks!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik your answer gave the context. No doubt about it.

Answer (score 2):

Because of initialization order rules in first case you call A() constructor before y was assigned to 10, so value of y is undefined and depends on current value of those sizeof(int) bytes in the stack. So you initialize x with that undefined semi-random value and print it later. In second case you call B(int) with s = 4 and it successfully initializes x with 4.